# Blackberry Simulator - printing only relevant debug messages

Tags: debugging, logging, blackberry

When debugging in the blackberry simulator, the console prints out a lot of other information relevant to the simulator along with the debug information printed in the application I develop. Is there a way to print only the debug messages of the application I am running in the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always format my debug messages in specific way:

```
System.out.print("   ---RTP:"+message);
```

So it's easy to find specific message from my app.
Also, it's great to scrollock console searching or reading messages.

Comment: Thanks, I too do something similar, however wading through the messages being printed is a pain. Do we have some flags or something to prevent the simulator from printing its own messages?

Comment: It would be great to have such ability, but I can't find it... BTW, EventLog may be an alternative.